# I need something like average, but with 'force'

Tags: average

Say I have two teams with different scores.

- Team A = 500 points
- Team B = 700 points

Obviously `(500 + 700) / 2` will give me the average score of 600.

But now, I would like to assign 'weight' or 'relevance' to each team's score. Let's say `Team B = 100%` and team `A = 50%`. How can I calculate a new "average" that'll take into consideration that team A score is carries only 'half the weight' as team B?

Obviously the average in this case should be above 600 in that scenario, because team A's 500 score will not "drag" it down as as much anymore, but only 'half' the drag-down...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called a "weighted average".  Multiply each team's score by the team's weight; then add the weighted scores; then divide by the total weight.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the term "weighted average".

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{500 \times 0.5+700\times 1}{0.5+1}=633.33$

Easy to calculate if we use $A:B=1:2$ for your example.

$\dfrac{500 \times 1+700\times 2}{1+2}=633.33$